# How to launch unit tests separately from integration tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0

Say I have several dlls of unit tests and a couple of dlls of integration tests.
I want to rerun all unit tests by a click or by a hotkey for example.

How to accomplish that using Visual Studio 2013? By the way I have DotCover and ReSharper from JetBrains, maybe these tools can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 / MSTest has a feature called *playlist*.

You might create a playlist of integration tests and other one of unit tests, and this should be enough for you, since you'll be able to execute:

- All tests (this won't need a playlist).
- Integration tests separately (*Integration test playlist*).
- Unit tests separately (*Unit test playlist*).

Learn more about playlists [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx).